# Eclipse: JAVA_HOME not set

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
JAVA HOME is not set correctly.
```

I am getting the following error when I try to run web server in Eclipse:

The system cannot find the path specified.
JAVA HOME is not set correctly.

But checking my env variables they look correct:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Installation;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Installation;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Installation;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;
```

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: It is looking correct.. Check it on Cmd... java -version.. Close the cmd and reopen it then try

Comment: Yeah that looks OK:

java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode, sharing)

javac -version
javac 1.8.0_101

Just doesn't work in Eclipse for some reason

Comment: Try to close and reopen the eclipse .. it should work

Comment: That is the best thing to do in such case, at least you would know whether the eclipse is causing the problem or the environment variables. Try running a simple java file from cmd.

Comment: @En-Motion you can go to Windows->Preferences... and choose Java->Installed JREs. In Eclipse and set the JRE path there

Comment: It will run and compile a simple java class. But I'm trying to run a servlet on  a Java Web Server and that's where I get the error

Comment: Which web server are you trying to run with eclipse? I don't think this situation is related to eclipse. Try to run the server in command-line and test if the problem persists. Maybe the spaces and/or the `(x86)` in the path generates the problem.

Comment: How exactly did you configure the server I wonder, because it seems to be run through a shell script? With a proper plugin (which may already be installed in Eclipse for JavaEE developers) the server can generally be started by Eclipse itself and you have no such problems at all.

Comment: The server is on the local machine? does he have access to these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for system environment variables and user environment variables... seems like eclipse is taking variables from different environment..

If problem persist then set the JAVA_HOME in eclipse to tell eclipse explicitly where java is installed in the system. To set JAVA_HOME in eclispe few options given below.

To set JAVA_HOME in eclipse navigate to windows menu -> preferences -> Add runtime variables

OR

Navigate to Run menu -> External Tools configurations -> Navigate to environment tab -> Add JAVA_HOME variable and it's path as it's value to set environment variable in eclipse.

Comment: eclipse is not opening as well. so cant really set this is menu

Comment: Second option worked for me, I had to do it in "Run Configuration" configuration for my maven configuration, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

actually the path/classpath/any setting is on "Administrator" privilege and will NOT be accessed if eclipse is started directly.
right click on eclipse.exe and select "Run As Administrator".

hope it works

Comment: why you posting your gmail  id with answer?

Comment: @HelloWorld, because he want to say Hello to the world ? ;) (sorry, too easy)

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bug in Eclipse to me.

Eclipse comes with Java built in already. It's somewhere deep down in Eclipse. Users have no idea where it is.
Only Eclipse itself can set JAVA_HOME properly.

Installing your own Java and setting JAVA_HOME to point to there seems a bad idea, introducing potential conflicts between the built-in java version and JAVA_HOME contents